# How do I submit a form on keypress 'enter' with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

How do I keypress the key enter to submit my coupon code in mobile and desktop? 
Keypress enter is not working, I have to click the submit button so the coupon code will apply. Did I make some mistake?

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    testKey();
});
 function testKey() {
        $("#inputbox").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        }
    });
    }
```

PHP

```
<form id="testt" action="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

            <div class="coupon">

                <?php if ( WC()->cart->coupons_enabled() ) { ?>

                <span for="coupon_code"><?php _e( 'Coupon code:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span> 

                <div class="input-container">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <input id="inputbox" class="input" type="text" name="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'bebrave', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> 
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="ds btn" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>

                <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>

            </div>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>

        </form>
```

Comment: If you debug in this line if (event.which == 13) { what is the value of event and event.which?

Comment: I don't even understand why you have that javascript code.. you are trying to prevent the default form's submit action, and then submiting it with a function..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I press the keyboard "Enter" key to enter the coupon code in mobile and desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905787/how-do-i-press-the-keyboard-enter-key-to-enter-the-coupon-code-in-mobile-and-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want submit your form using the Enter key, use something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inputbox').keypress(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#testt').submit();
    }
 });
});
```

To listen on the keypress event, out of any function.
If you are focus on the #inputbox input, the logic inside the condition will be called.

**EDIT**

It's just perfectly working.
I have made a fiddle for you, that call the on-submit event of your form on hit enter in your #inputbox :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chalas_r/v4pfkd8k/14/)

Comment: You are using the same code that i have above, so it's not working. @chalasr

Comment: You have written the code inside another function, also if the function is not called, the even listener doesn't work.

Comment: i did call the function. but it's not working. sorry i didn't mention that.

$(document).ready(function() {
    testKey();
});   

@chalasr

Comment: Look at my answer, I've added a fiddle .

Comment: yes yours work. i think i have some problem with it :( @chalasr

Comment: Have you tried with the updated code ? I use the id of your form to submit it, instead of `closest()`.
Otherwise, the problem is surely not about this part of your code.
Try to replace your code by the fiddle's code, maybe you can found your mistake.

Comment: Please create a fiddle and show all your html. What error you get ? The form is not submitted ?is there an error in your browser's console ?

Comment: using your fiddle, I can't type in the input box. can you type? @chalasr

Comment: sorry it's fixed, my bad.

Comment: i still can't type :( @chalasr

Comment: I have re-updated it ! don't hit update, just re-click on the link. the `e.preventDefault()` must be in the if ...

Comment: i click the fiddle link, but its not working.  is this the update code? https://jsfiddle.net/chalas_r/v4pfkd8k/7/ @chalasr

Comment: Thank you. it works. when I type and then press the enter key. it will alert "submitted" but my coupon code didn't apply. do you know why?

Comment: Replace the HTML by yours, with your php. I have updated the fiddle with your html : https://jsfiddle.net/chalas_r/v4pfkd8k/17/ , just copy and paste

Comment: thank you. but it's still not working for me. coupon  code is not applying.

Comment: Your question is how submit form on hit enter key in jQuery. If you have another question about your php code (that is surely wrong, because what I've done for you is exactly the same as click on the submit button), submit it. Also you should really close this question because it's off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

How about simulating clicking the submit button when pressing Enter in the text box ? try something like

```
$("#inputbox").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('input[type=submit]').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: put up an alert immediately inside the keypress event handler. Does it trigger ?

Comment: yes. alert($(this).closest('input[type=submit]').click());  it alert "[object Object]" .  @Anudeep Bulla

Comment: then can you try alerting just AFTER the click event ?If it alert, then it is trying to submit. Maybe there is something wrong in the PHP side ?

Comment: When I click the submit button, my coupon code applied. But when i keypress it, the coupon code is not applying. @Anudeep Bulla